# What is this 'timestamp' key returned from Maven's REST API?

Tags: python, json, rest, maven

I am using Maven's REST API to obtain data on artifacts in the repository programmatically with Python.  In the returned results I have an interesting JSON key that makes no sense to me. Here is one of the results I obtain from my script:

```
{
  "id": "junit:junit:4.1",
  "g": "junit",
  "a": "junit",
  "v": "4.1",
  "p": "jar",
  "timestamp": 1160134625000,
  "tags": [
    "kent",
    "regression",
    "junit",
    "used",
    "framework",
    "unit",
    "gamma",
    "tests",
    "developer",
    "written",
    "implements",
    "beck",
    "testing",
    "java",
    "erich"
  ],
  "ec": [
    "-javadoc.jar",
    "-sources.jar",
    ".jar",
    ".pom"
  ]
}
```

My question is what is the '*timestamp*' key? This number does not make any sense to me. Is this something in relation to the number of seconds since the Unix epoch or what?

Also, I was  hoping to find the information on the '*Updated*' date field that one sees when going to the web interface for the same query as shown at this URL: http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22junit%22

Here is the Maven API REST query I am using to obtain the JSON shown above: `http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:junit+AND+a:junit&core=gav&rows=1000&wt=json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

divide it by 1000 and you can use it with datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()

Comment: Wow you must be a wizard; this works! I can see the date as though it were human readable in the web browser now. Thank-you so much for the reply One. :D